# Post request to login in React Native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, mongoose

I'm making a POST request to an API, this request should return an response  if the encrypted passwords match. Right now it returns undefined, and in my app throw a catch alert.

This is the api code:

```js
async login(req, res){
        const { user, password } = req.body
        const userLogin = await User.findOne({user: user})
        const compare = bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, res){
            if(err){
                if(err) {throw (err)}
            }

            bcrypt.compare(password, userLogin.password, function(err, res){
                if(err) {throw (err)}
                return res
            })

        })
        console.log(compare)
        return res.json(compare)              
    }
```

This is my component:

```
state = {
      user: '',
      password: '',
    } 

    login = async () => {
        await api.post("/userLogin", {
          user: this.state.user,
          password: this.state.password
        })
        .then(res => {
          if(res.data == true){
            this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'EscolhaTimes' })
          }else{
            Alert.alert('Usuário ou senha errados')
          }
        }).catch(
          Alert.alert('Error')
        )
    }
    render() {

        return (
          <LinearGradient
          start={{x: 0, y: 1}} end={{x: 1, y:0}}
          colors={['#313056', '#221f3a']}
          style={Patern.linearGradient}
          >
            <View style={Patern.container} >
                <Image source={require('./img/logo.png')} style={Patern.logoStyle}/>
                <Text style={Patern.textoazul}> LOGIN </Text>
                <TextInput autoFocus={true} 
                  value={this.state.user} 
                  onChangeText={user => this.setState({user})} 
                  placeholder="USUÁRIO" 
                  placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF"  
                  style={Patern.inputStyle} />
                <TextInput style={Patern.inputStyle}
                value={this.state.password} 
                onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}  
                placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF" 
                placeholder="SENHA" 
                secureTextEntry={true} />
                <View style={Patern.buttonContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
                       this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Cadastro' })               
                    } style={Patern.bottomCadastro}>
                    <Text style={Patern.textoCadastro}>NÃO SOU CADASTRADO</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this.login} style={Patern.buttonStyle}>
                    <Text style={Patern.buttonText}>ENTRAR</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
```

How can I make my login work?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is your current code?

.catch( Alert.alert('Error'))

Maybe you want:
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err.message)});

Then check the error message.

Comment: Doesn't return anything. Maybe the problem is the backend, the compare code is returning undefined.